# Advice on good Node Express Multipart File Upload middleware for inversify-express-utils controller

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I am working on a project for work, Using Typescript and ExpressJs they use [inversify-express-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inversify-express-utils) for the controllers for all their endpoints.  I was given a task to add a file upload backend endpoint to ingest a file (csv, pdf, dat) that could be a few bytes to upwards of 100Mb.

I am looking for advice for a multipart file upload structure (AND EXAMPLES) that works with inversify-express-utils.

Is Multer still one of the better file upload middlewares for node?  If so are there any examples on how to fold it into a inversify-express-utils controller?  I could not find any during my search over the last hour. Perhaps my Google Foo is lacking.

Is there a better file upload middleware for node/typescript/express/inversify-express-utils? And if so are there any code examples on getting it to work?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I just cannot get multer to work with Inversify

Comment: yes moved it to middleware on the controller endpoint

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example endpoint with a Multer upload in 'inversify' with 'inversify-express-utils'

```
import * as express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
import {
  BaseHttpController,
  controller
  httpPost,
} from 'inversify-express-utils';
import { inject } from 'inversify';


const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024 },
});


@controller('/v1')
export class v1Controller extends BaseHttpController {
  constructor(){
      super();
  }
    
  @httpPost('/', upload.single('file'))
  private async upload(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
      const { file, body } = req;
      // Do what you will with the file contents as type Express.Multer.File type
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent so much time trying to bind it to the container and getting errors I ended up using a different library, and yet it's so simple.